# Understanding unitTest on laravel 4

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn how the UnitTest work on laravel. I understand how to test a controller and a model. What I don't understand is how to test my own class.

**Let's say as an example:**

I made a Class called Chat in `app/core/chat/chat.php`. In this case I would like test my first method `load()`. How can I tell to the class `ChatTest` that I want to test that method?

I tried to instance the class on my method passing it the mock interfaces (binded on IoC) and say that the current class shouldReceive load once, but it give me the error that the method load should be call 1 time but it called 0 times. Where am I making a mistake?

**Class Chat**

```
<?php namespace Core\Chat\Chat;

use Core\Chat\Chat\Models\MessageInterface;
use Core\Chat\Chat\Models\ConversationInterface;

Class Chat { 
    function __construct(ConversationInterface $conversation,MessageInterface $message) { 
        $this->conversation = $conversation;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->app = app();
    }

    /**
    * Get Messages of a conversation, on the current user
    *
    * @param $user_id | id user id
    * @return Bool | true | False
    */

    public function load($user_id) {
        $conversation = $this->exist( $user_id, $this->app['sentry']->getUser()->id );
        if ($conversation) {
            $messages = $this->conversation->loadConversation($conversation->id);    
            $this->status = "success";
            $this->response = $messages;
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->status = "error";
            $this->response = "no conversation";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class ChatTest**

```
<?php

use \Mockery;

/**
 * Class ChatTest
 */
class ChatTest extends TestCase { 
    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_load_messages_conversation() {    
        $convInterface = Mockery::mock('Core\Chat\Chat\Models\ConversationInterface');
        $messInterface = Mockery::mock('Core\Chat\Chat\Models\MessageInterface');
        $chat = new Chat($convInterface,$messInterface);
        $chat->shouldReceive('load')->once();
        // error it should be called 1 time but it called 0 times.              
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeffery Way has written a book called LARAVEL TESTING DECODED (http://laravel-testing.com/books/laravel-testing-decoded), you may want to get that, it covers how to unit test Laravel projects

Comment: Thanks for the book suggested i'll read that soon as possible. On the while i'm still corious on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to call *shouldReceive* in Mockery instances, those methods that are called inside the Chat class that aren't part of that class, so when you test the Chat class, you are not depending on other classes responses. In this case something like this (not a fully working code but hope to give you a hint of what I would do in this case):

```
$sentryMock->shouldReceive('getUser')->andReturn(new User);
$convMock->shouldReceive('loadConversation')->andReturn(new MessageInterface);
$chat = new Chat(); //should be working with IoC bindings
$this->assertTrue($chat->load());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate so much your example I understood the way, but it is just not clear on how i can test the method exist() that belong to the same class:)